# Replace content links domain depending on environment in contentful

Tags: content-management-system, contentful

Below is some info to have context about the problem I am looking for solution:

"I only want to have a prod environment for contentful. the preview url is being used for UAT and Dev environments. So if the content is in the draft it will be reflected in Dev and UAT and when published it will be reflected in both environments as well as Prod".

Now the issue is there are some links in content that has a prod domain like www.[prod-domain]/blah blah, I need those URLs domain to be replaced with UAT or Dev domains in the draft (depending on environment) like www.[UAT-domain].blah blah

Is there any middleware for this? if not, what's the best way to achieve this in-app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salma from Contentful here!

If you use relative links in the content (e.g. /blahblah), they would automatically resolve to the current domain when navigated to on the front end.

If you're using Rich Text and outputting links in the flow of the text, you could get around the protocol requirement in the usual link formatter by creating a custom 'internal link' entry content type, which you can embed as an inline entry. For this content type, you could ask editors to provide a path to a page without the https protocol and domain, and ensure there is validation for that in the web app (using the pattern validation).

Another option would be to remove the protocol and domain from the urls when rendering on the front end to avoid the editors having to create extra entries when adding content to the Rich Text field.